# Make edges on graph line round and not "sharp" Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, graph, swiftui

I am currently working on a graph view for a widget and I don't like the way the edges looks on my graph atm. I would like to make the edges on my graph line rounded instead of sharp ([Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUmRz.png)).
I've tried with .cornerRadius(5) and .addQuadCurve() but nothing seems to work.

My code looks like this.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 14.0.0, *)

struct Graph: View {

    var styling = ViewStyling()
    var stockPrices: [CGFloat]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient:
                        Gradient(colors: [styling.gradientColor, styling.defaultWhite]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .clipShape(LineGraph(dataPoints: stockPrices.normalized, closed: true))

        LineGraph(dataPoints: stockPrices.normalized)
            .stroke(styling.graphLine, lineWidth: 2)
            //.cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0.0, *)
struct LineGraph: Shape {
    var dataPoints: [CGFloat]
    var closed = false

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    
        func point(at ix: Int) -> CGPoint {
            let point = dataPoints[ix]
            let x = rect.width * CGFloat(ix) / CGFloat(dataPoints.count - 1)
            let y = (1 - point) * rect.height
        
            return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        }
    
        return Path { p in
        
            guard dataPoints.count > 1 else { return }
        
            let start = dataPoints[0]
            p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (1 - start) * rect.height))
            //p.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), control: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        
            for index in dataPoints.indices {
                 p.addLine(to: point(at: index))
            }

            if closed {
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
                p.closeSubpath()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element == CGFloat {
    // Return the elements of the sequence normalized.
    var normalized: [CGFloat] {
        if let min = self.min(), let max = self.max() {
            return self.map{ ($0 - min) / (max - min) }
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot run your code, what is **ViewStyling()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the joins between line segments are rendered is controlled by the `lineJoin` property of `StrokeStyle`, You're stroking with a color and a line width here:

```
.stroke(styling.graphLine, lineWidth: 2)
```

but you want something more like:

```
.stroke(styling.graphline, StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineJoin: .round))
```

Comment: I used this. All the options in lineJoin don't work at all. They always show sharp corners. I'm using swift5, iOS 15. Does anyone has the solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Also used this ```.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round))``` with no success

Comment: @lopes710 please ask a separate question